# Refresh the page once res.redirect() loads

Tags: javascript, express, routes, backend

Basically i'm making an article website just for learning purposes.

When the user adds a new article, it should redirect him to home page.

Testing it and creating a new article, i expected to be available once i got redirected to home page, but it only shows up if i hit refresh, so `res.redirect()` is basically redirecting  me to the home page previously loaded, instead of properly activating the route. There is some method like `refresh()` or something that i should be aware of?

Thank's in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had just found the trouble

```
// I was doing this:
  Article.findAll()
    .then( res.redirect("/home") );

// Correct way to do it:
  Article.findAll()
    .then( () => {
       res.redirect( "/home" )
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you'd be looking for is `location.reload();`

or in this case you could give `document.reload()` or `window.reload()` a go

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location/reload